# SDCC dependency generation

Tags: sdcc

I'm trying to generate header file dependencies with SDCC on Windows, the command line is

`sdcc -c -mmcs51 --model-small --xram-size 0x0100 --xram-loc 0x0100 --code-size 0x2800 -Iinclude/ -oobj/ -DFREQ_SYS=12000000 --std-c23 -MMD -MT 'obj/main.rel' -MF 'obj/main.d' src/main.c`

Which gives me this error:
`at 1: error 119: don't know what to do with file 'obj/main.d'. file extension unsupported`

The SDCC manual says: "SDCC uses sdcpp, an adapted version of the GNU Compiler Collection preprocessor cpp (gcc gcc. gnu.org/). If you need more dedicated options than those listed below please refer to the GCC CPP Manual at gnu.org/software/gcc/onlinedocs."

Is it possible the `-MT` and `-MF` options not supported?

The GCC docs mention these options but perhaps they're not passed through? In which case, does anyone have any good ideas about how to generate dependencies with SDCC without resorting to grep and sed etc?

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Using the -MMD option on its own generates a rule which uses a backslash for the target which then is interpreted as an escape, so the rule never fires.

e.g.
`obj\main.rel: src/main.c include/ch554.h include/ch554_usb.h include/debug.h`

I *think* the target is being interpreted as `objmain.rel` because it never fires

Confirmed the backslash was the problem, now I have this sed expression in the rule which makes me sad but does work

`sed -r -i 's#^(.*)\\\\(.*)\\:#\\1\\/\\2:#' $(OBJ)$(basename $(@F)).d`

Comment: 1. What does the SDCC manual say about passing of option? 2. Did you add that `-c` option by purpose? It request a compilation, but you don't want that here.

Comment: The SDCC manual says: "SDCC uses sdcpp, an adapted version of the GNU Compiler Collection preprocessor cpp (gcc http://gcc.
gnu.org/). If you need more dedicated options than those listed below please refer to the GCC CPP Manual at
http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/onlinedocs/."

Comment: Why don't I want compilation?

Comment: (As always: please add new information to your question, not as a comment.) -- You want to generate the dependency files before the compilation, so that the following dependency tree is complete before make attempts to compile your program. Separate concerns.

Comment: Not sure I follow the logic - if the source file is being compiled anyway then the dependency information will be valid thereafter, which is what's required. Is there a scenario I haven't thought of where this wouldn't work?

Comment: Are you writing your own makefiles? Did you consider using cmake or basel?

Comment: I am, I did and will not be using either of those things

Comment: Think about the case, if because of the existing dependencies the action is not triggered. Then the dependency file is not updated, but might need to. The dependency needs to be updated and known before make decides whether to compile or not. -- Anyway, you are to do what you want...

Comment: But won't the existing dependencies be correct if make has run at least once?

Comment: So you want to run the compile command, which needs to be based on a correct and up-to-date dependency graph, before this dependency graph is updated? Well, do so. You will know when it breaks. ;-)

Comment: if you think about it a bit more you'll get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no space between `MF` and filename.

```
-MFobj/main.d
```

I think in sdcc you should do like, idea from https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/bugs/3551/ :

```
sdcc -Wp,-MMD,-MTobj/main.rel,-MFmain.d ./main.c
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, this works very nicely

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck And it does not compile at the same time. ;-)

Comment: Actually I have it compiling and generating the dependencies in a single step, works great: $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wp,-MMD,-MT$(OBJ)$(basename $(@F)).rel,-MF$(OBJ)$(basename $(@F)).d $<